# Derivative of composition functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f,g$ be two functions such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$. If $f(2)=5$, $f'(5)=2$, what's the value of $g'(5)$?

First it's easy to see that $g(5)=g(f(2))=2$; also using chain rule, $1=f'(g(x))g'(x)=g'(f(x))f'(x)$. But I can't proceed from here. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: The condition says $f$ and $g$ are inverses. There's a result you can use.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you so much; I shoudn't have missed such an obvious property

Comment: In your last formula plug in $x=2.$